# Using Aws S3 bucket for Static website and ec2 wordpress blog for a single domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have already configured AWS s3 bucket and hosted a Static Website and i have also installed bitnami wordpress and i want my visitor to show static website when opened and when Clicked on Example.com/blog it should show the wordpress installed .
Guide me the possible way to do this

Comment: I am assuming that you have created your bucket with name example.com now do one thing create a folder inside your bucket with name blog and put your content inside. Have you done that ?

Comment: I have created the bucket name as said above by you .But I have installed WordPress with bitnami in instance Ec2 so how could I move that ?

Comment: If you are trying to move your ec2 instance which is actually on bitnami provided Wordpress so it just wanna confirm if you trying to run a php site on s3 which is not possible.   Still confusing statement you have ec2 Wordpress site now wanna to route on example.com/blog from s3 such routing are possible using AWS ALB which works on target path based routing

Comment: And path based routing didn’t work with ALB and ec2 and S3 combination actually this is not even a use case of s3  and yes you can use S3 to hold your content of Wordpress like media even your static code but routing with an ec2 hosted example.com to example.com/blog won’t work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem by Connecting EC2 with Sftp , Bitvise and Transferred all the word press files to a new folder and Aws s3 bucket files to the Ec2 .

So now i forwarded the public ip to a domain name and got the results as expected